# Diagonalising a matrix: does order of eigenvectors matter?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

So suppose I have a matrix $A$ with real distinct eigenvalues, and I am finding the diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D = P^{-1}A P$. Then $P$ consists of columns that are eigenvectors of $A$. In what order do I put these columns in $P$? And does this order matter, or would I always get the same $D$ no matter in what order I arrange these columns?

P.S. Another thing - if I take various multiples of the eigenvectors and use them in $P$, again how does this affect the result $D$?

Comment: The important thing is that the order of the eigenvectors in $P$ matches the order of the eigenvalues in $D$. Replacing each eigenvector in $P$ with a (non-zero) multiple does **not** affect $D$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann why not answer?

Comment: @KennyLau I think that a full answer in this context requires an example and possibly justification, which I do not have the patience to put together.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with your postscript question: Any non-zero multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector for the same eigenvalue. So multiplying various columns by non-zero values will leave $P$ still a matrix of eigenvectors, which is all you need.

To fill in the rest of Ben Grossman's comment, consider the matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\-4&1\end{bmatrix}$$
The eigenvalues are obviously $-1,1$. And
$$A-(1)I = \begin{bmatrix}-2&0\\-4&0\end{bmatrix},\quad A-(-1)I = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\-4&2\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$ is a eigenvector for $-1$, and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for $1$.

So let $$P_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\2&1\end{bmatrix}, \quad P_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$$
So $$P_1^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-2&1\end{bmatrix}, \quad P_2^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$P_1^{-1}AP_1 = \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ while $$P_2^{-1}AP_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

The order of the eigenvectors in $P$ determines the order in which the eigenvalues appear in $D$.